# Reducing data points

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to present data thats being stored per second over a whole day. So 86400 points per excel sheet. Creating a line chart from that isn't looking pretty and very slow, obviously.

To reduce data I can use maximum value per minute, or perhaps even multiple minutes, but I have no idea how to create a table for that. My raw data set looks like this:

```
8-12-2023  06:59:30, 57.8
8-12-2023  06:59:31, 56.3
```

Is there a option for a line chart to do this? Or otherwise how would i create a table to shrink my data using maximum values per time range.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a PivotTable for this: put the date and time into Rows section (it will automatically split it into hours/minutes/seconds), expand to the level you want (for instance, minutes), and put the (max of) value into the values Section. Use the classic pivottable appearance to avoid summary rows.

Now you can make a chart based on the pivottable. It will look something like this: [image]